# Oblate Spheroidal coordinate system graphic representation of ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I am having difficulty understanding how to interpret the coordinate system proposed by Spencer. From his handbook Field Theory Handbooks ISBN 9783540184300 proposed a system with the domains illustrated in the picture.

The domain of `eta` represents the curvilinear axis represented by the ellipse rotating around the minor axis. What exactly is the characteristic of the ellipse in the picture?  Is 'Eta' representing a number describing the  minor or mayor axis of the ellipse?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither or both, depending on your point of view. Refer to the illustration: the surfaces with $\eta$ held constant are oblate spheriods. From the equations of the transformation to Cartesian coordinates, these spheroids have the parameterization $$\begin{align}x &= (a\cosh\eta)\sin\theta\cos\psi \\ y &= (a\cosh\eta)\sin\theta\sin\psi \\ z &= (a\sinh\eta)\cos\theta.\end{align}$$ I’ve added parentheses to emphasize the constant quantity in each equation. The half-axis lengths of the spheroid are therefore $a\cosh\eta$ and $a\sinh\eta$. Similarly, the surfaces with constant $\theta$ are hyperboloids of revolution with half-axis lengths $a\cos\theta$ and $a\sin\theta$. The angle $\theta$ represents the aperture half-angle of the hyperboloid’s asymptotic cone. Surfaces with constant $\psi$ are half-planes that make an angle of $\psi$ with the positive $x$-$z$ half-plane.

Comment: Thanks for your clear details of the constant. I could not see this.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\psi=$ constant sectioning plane containing z-axis we have *confocal conic sections* with the marked  $F$ as common focal locus for variable $\eta$ value on all ellipses formed by cutting planes$\psi=$ constant.

Parametrization for horizontal ellipse sections

$$ r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = a \cosh \eta \sin \theta ;\, z = a \sinh \eta \cos \theta; $$
$$ \big(\frac{r}{a \cosh \eta}\big)^2 + \big(\frac{r}{a \sinh \eta}\big)^2 =1 $$
$$ \epsilon^2= 1- \frac{\sinh^2 \eta}{\cosh ^2\eta}= sech^2 \eta $$

So have $\epsilon =sech\, \eta$ geometrically interpreted as eccentricity of horizontal ellipses  formed by  cutting planes parallel to $x-y$ plane.

Circular conicoids when $\eta \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: @ Narasimham From where is  derrived  the eccentricity= =ℎ ?

Comment: Is the edit clear enough? $ \epsilon  = sech \eta \le 1 $